# Local Javascript File with Google Hangout API without HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ssl, google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I am adding a google hangout api to my application, and am trying to keep the JS locally for development purposes.

The XML file is available publicly on a server (as required by google).

The only way I was able to get it to work right now is to point the XML file to my local server using an HTTPS protocol. Otherwise, I get an error in the JS browser console that the insecure JS code is blocked.

This is the snippet that asks for the local JS file:

```
<script src="//localhost:3000/hangouts.js"></script>
```

The Hangout documentation and example apps don't reference https in any way and make it seem like it should work out of the box with a local JS file, so hopefully this can serve as another point of reference.

It seems like a pain to have to run the local server with SSL in development mode, so I'm wondering if there is a way around this or a better way to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [hangoutiframer](https://hangoutiframer.appspot.com/static/help.html). It's a tool that provides an interface to automatically generate an .xml file that wraps an HTML page, and allows you to host your html where ever you want during developmen.